# How to Calculate Number of Samples for Concurrent users using either jp@gc-Ultimate Group or Concurrency Thread Group in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, quality-assurance

Running 10 Thread with 10 sec of start up delay and 10 sec hold and 10 sec shutdown time

Below is the link jmeter setup for configuration https://i.stack.imgur.com/31Slv.png

Below is the link - summary report for above configuration https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB2w8.png

Please let me know how the sample request are calculated for above configuration i.e 10 thread for 10 sec delay and 10 sec hold of concurrency testing.

Huge thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

They are not calculated, the actual number of samples depend on your application response time.

Looking into your scenario:

- JMeter will start with 1 thread
- Each 1 second a new thread will be added
- The test will run for 10 seconds
- Then JMeter will shut down 1 thread each 1 second
- When all threads are shut down - the test ends
- Once thread (virtual user) is started it begins executing [Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) (in your case - single [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler) **as fast as it can**, to wit:

  - send the request
  - wait for response
  - start over

So

- if your application response time will be 1000 milliseconds - you will have around 200 executions
- if your application response time will be 500 milliseconds - you will have around 400 executions
- if your application response time will be 2000 milliseconds - you will have around 100 executions
- etc.

If you want to limit the number of executions to some specific value - go for [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)

---

P.S. I see 7 [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) in your Test Plan. Be informed that Listeners should be used only for tests development and debugging, in fact [listeners don't add any value and only consume resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing) as all the information which is displayed is available in .jtl results file. So once you're happy with your test and verified that it's doing what it is supposed to be doing:

1. Disable or delete all the listeners in the test plan
2. [Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
3. Once test execution finishes you will be able to open the `result.jtl` file with the Listener of your choice or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of it.